# hide() in jquery

Tags: jquery

In a jquery code, I am dynamically showing and hiding some content.

```
            if (this.hide()) {

                this.show();
                                }
            else {
                alert("Hello");
                this.hide();

            }
```

But else part is never getting executed.why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do something like this :

```
if($(this).is(':hidden')) { 
    $(this).show();
}
else {
  $(this).hide();
}
```

Or depending on what you want to do, you can try `toggle()`

Comment: I'd go for the toggle option in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is

```
this.toggle();
```

The reason you never reach your 'else' clause is because `hide()` returns the elements found in the selector (for method chaining reasons). Since it always returns a valid object, it will always resolve to "truthy", i.e. not `null, "", 0, false`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`this.hide()` is running the hide function, not checking if it's hidden, thus it's setting it to hide and then running `this.show()`

as already said `toggle()` is what you want as it does the check for you without having to code for that.

Answer (score 0):

In the if you are hidding the element.
You should do this.is(':hidden')